# PyTorch: Logging during model.fit()

Tags: python, pytorch, fast-ai

I'm using pytorch/fastai for training models. Since I'm working with remote machines, I am running the scripts using `nohup python $1 >$2 2>&1 &` with redirection to logging file like `"log123.txt"`.

My problem is that during the `model.fit()` phase with scheduler, I can't see the progress in the file after each epoch like in console and the results are written to my logging file after the model.fit() finishes training. It works fine when I watch the process in console.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to file buffering. You can disable it for python process like this:

1. Run your script with `-u` options. Example:

`python -u my_script.py > log.txt`

2. Use `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`:

`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 python my_script.py > log.txt`

or

```
export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
python my_script.py > log.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem and it works as expected now.